# Simultaneous use of ssr and spa in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I have a shop site that I want the front part to be in ssr mode
The user panel and login and registration should be loaded as spa

Do you know how I can do this? And how will the routes settings be? that does not happen to ssr

Comment: Hi, please give a read to that one: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.